# How to set Logo/Profile Picture with mailgun

Tags: node.js, mailgun

I am using mailgun to send emails from my app. Everything is working perfectly. I am receivng mails but one important thing that I need to implement is setting the profile picture for the mail to make the email more profesional looking.

[image]

Comment: That picture doesn't come from code or email headers. It's populated by address book. If you're using Outlook within an organization then that may pull in from a company address book. If you only care about GMail I think you used to be able to pull some trickery by creating a Google+ account bound to the email, but you wouldn't be able to get mailgun to fake that anyway. Maybe there's something new that would allow you to do it that someone else can contribute, but last I checked, you won't be able to do what you want to do.

Comment: Have you looked into the [BIMI standard](https://bimigroup.org/verified-mark-certificates-vmc-and-bimi/)?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like service providers like Mailgun have no way to control the display of sender profile photo. Quoting from one of their articles - https://www.mailgun.com/blog/email/including-a-sender-image/

> Email Service Providers like Mailgun have no control over the display images that show up next to the Friendly From in a recipient’s mailbox. The image formatting is controlled by the various mailbox providers – Yahoo, Microsoft Outlook, Apple Mail etc. –, their unique methods and protocols, and the email clients that interact with them.

The article also states that new processes like BIMI are available, but with limited support of email clients - https://bimigroup.org/bimi-generator/

Hope this helps!